# From a Lacanian perspective, why did Kurtz go mad in Heart of Darkness?

Tags: joseph-conrad, heart-of-darkness, psychoanalysis, jacques-lacan

From a Lacanian perspective, what would be the cause of Kurtz's madness? Would it be reasonable to argue that when he was confronted with the "horror" of the colonial project and the way that Western civilisation is a veneer, Kurtz was forced to abandon the interpellations of his youth, giving way to his libidinal desires and a state of psychosis?

Sub-questions:

Are there any examples of the Real in the novella?

Is it fair to say that Kurtz is Marlow's mirror?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. I wonder whether you could rephrase your question somewhat so it looks less speculative and more focused? For example, you might just focus on "From a Lacanian perspective, what is Kurtz's madness?" "Is it fair to say that Kurtz is ...?" may then be moved to the bottom as a subquestion (if it is strongly related) rather than at the top. Stack Exchange wants question to have a clear focus.